# Mysql database - import files to new database

Tags: php, mysql

When I want to move my database to new server, I get this error.

> SQL: #1067 - Invalid default value for 'jailtime'

Jailtime: Datetime, Current_Timestamp.

Any ideas how can I fix this? As I can remember, I created a SQL which if pJailed row gets modified,  Jailtime row gets Current_Timetsamp.

server 5.5.49 - MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi
phpmyadmin: 4.0.10.20

Can I provide any details in plus to help you to help me? Thanks.

Later Edit: I read multiple stackoverflow questions about related, found answers like NO_ZERO_DATE.,  but when I tried to find

```
show variables like 'sql_mode' ;
```

I don't have the sql mode  `"NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE`

Tried even the

```
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
```

My triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER `logsupdate` BEFORE UPDATE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW begin if new.pJailed <> old.pJailed then set new.jailtime = now(); end if; if new.pVIP <> old.pVIP then set new.viplog = now(); end if; if new.pAdminLevel <> old.pAdminLevel then set new.adminlog = now(); end if; if new.pPoints <> old.pPoints then set new.TM4 = now(); end if; end
```

Comment: Please show us the create statement of this table. Also please reformat your question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, if someone has the same error.

Instead of Current_Timestamp,  define it as NULL :) It will work. And with NOW(); function still it will post the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Before the create statement just set the sql mode like this:

`SET sql_mode = '';`

In older versions of MySQL (MariaDB) zero dates were allowed by default, now they are not.